# Can a string be assigned to a char pointer, without it becoming a literal?

Tags: c, string, pointers, constants, literals

The question sounds a tad dumb, allow me to demonstrate what I mean.

I know that if I were to do something along the lines of:

```
(const) char *ptr = "I'm text!";
```

It'd be a literal I can't modify by any means later on. However, I figured, as there is a way to set up a pointer to work just like an array (on the heap), wouldn't it work to set up a string that way too? If yes, what'd be the easy way?

I tried the following, but it seems rather redundant, compared to just making an array and then assigning a pointer to it.

```
char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);

ptr[0]='S';
ptr[1]='u';
ptr[2]='p';
ptr[3]='e';
ptr[4]='r';
ptr[5]='\0';

printf("%s\n", ptr);  

free(ptr);
```

Comment: Maybe you want this: `char ptr[] = "I'm text!";`. This allows you to modify the string pointed to by `ptr`.

Comment: C does not have a string type. It is all convention. And a pointer is not an array (and vice-versa). What is your actual problem?

Comment: STFW for `strdup`; most systems (including POSIX) have it

Comment: `char *ptr = (char[]){"I'm text!"};`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: A _string literal_ **is** a `char []` already. No need for a compound literal.

Comment: @Olaf no, try [this](http://ideone.com/fxxvFz)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That's because the braces are optional for an initialiser of a scalar/pointer type. Your code is moush the same, except you explicitly use a literal. But - as the name says - it still is a _literal_, thus constant. Nothing gained. But fel free to make that an answer and elaborate. Maybe I overlooked something.

Comment: @Olaf So That `(char[])` is required. see [this](http://ideone.com/tpdPPv) too.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Hmm... Ok, [found your example in the standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5p12). I seem to have been misslead by the name. A compound literal actually is not constant. Now I understand why gcc allows non-constant initialisers. Thanks for pointing me at that. Make it an answer and I'll upvote.

Comment: @Olaf _A compound literal actually is not constant._ This is redundant, but `const char *ptr = (const char[]){"I'm text!"};` is possible.  I do not think a good answer because the lifetime is different from the literal. It is a limited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After allocating space to `char *` (*as you talk about it in example*), instead of doing character by character , you can use `strcpy` -

```
char *ptr = malloc((sizeof *ptr)*256);
if(ptr!=NULL) {                     // check return 
     strcpy(ptr,"super");
     //do something 
} 
free(ptr);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's all I wanted to know.

Comment: Looks more complicated than required by OP to me. Static allocation might be sufficient. But who knows, OP is no tquite clear what he actually needs.

Comment: @Olaf  Maybe but I responded this as OP  tried dynamic allocation in example  :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
char str[] = "eureka, this works";
```

Now you can modify the `char`s in it, using `str`, because it is essentially a `char` array. This means that certain operation like incrementing `str++` will not work.

---

However, if you strictly want to work with a pointer, then you can add another line to the above code.

```
char str[] = "eureka, this works";
char* ptr = str;
```

Now you can use `ptr`, operations like incrementing and all will work, since it is a pointer.

Comment: @Olaf, What I realized was he wants to initialize some certain way, and still want to modify it, just like a pointer. I can add more information clarifying it though.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that, I just wanted to know, if I was to "replicate" an array as a pointer on the heap, how I could "assign" the string in the most comfortable way possible. Thanks for your answer, anyway!

Comment: An array is not like a pointer. Itr just _decays_ to one for most use-cased. But there are very important differences. And "... just like a pointer" is a problematic statement. Try `str = "2nd text";` (I'm confident you know, but if not OP, there will be eventually other readers who don't).

Answer (score 2):

> There is difference between character array initialization and char
>   pointer initialization.
>
> Whenever you initialize a char pointer to point at a string literal,
>   the literal will be stored in the code section. You can not modify
>   code section memory. If you are trying to modify unauthorised memory
>   then you will get a segmentation fault.
>
> But if you initialize a char array, then it will be stored in the data
>   or stack section, depending on at where you declared the array. So you
>   can then modify the data.